# How to Determine App Capabilities in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, cameracapturetask

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg180730(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_wp8apps `The Windows Phone SDK 8.0 does not contain tools to detect the capabilities required for apps that target Windows Phone 8. When you submit an app that targets Windows Phone 8 to the Store, capabilities are not analyzed and the app manifest file is not regenerated or corrected.` In my application I am using CameraCaptureTask and ShareMediaTask to first capture a picture and then share. By default in my WMAppManifest file I had `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO`, `ID_CAP_NETWORKING`, and `ID_CAP_SENSORS`. I do in fact use the MediaLibrary t gather a photo path for the ShareMediaTask, so I have left that capability in WMAppManifest. Do I need the other two as well if the actual image capture and sharing occurs not within my application but within the CameraCaptureTask and ShareMediaTask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ShareMediaTask` does not have any capability requirements.

The `CameraCaptureTask` only requires that you specify the camera hardware capability.

For reference, the rules are defined in :

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Marketplace\Rules.xml"

Comment: In my project I currently have only specified `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO` to access the photos on the device itself. Even though I am using `CameraCaptureTask` I did not include `ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA` and it seems to be working on my device properly. Referencing my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213144/does-sharemediatask-require-a-data-connection/19243090?noredirect=1#19243090 that you answered, I'm assuming it's also the case that `CameraCaptureTask` does not have a capability requirement as well?

Comment: @Matthew that's right. `CameraCaptureTask` does not have a capability requirement.