# Does ShareMediaTask Require a Data Connection

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using the `ShareMediaTask` in my Windows Phone 8 application, and I am trying to determine the specific capabilities and requirements on a users device. Does a users Data Connection have to be turned on on their device for the ShareMediaTask to successfully send a picture? Also, is it required to have ID_CAP_NETWORKING checked in my application's WMAppManifest for ShareMediaTask to work? Must both of these be on?

What I have is ID_CAP_NETWORKING off in my WMAppManifest, which I do not believe is require for ShareMediaTask, but my device's Data Connection switched to On in the phone settings. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ShareMediaTask` does not have any capability requirements for inclusion within your app.

However, for the user to be able to actually share the media they will need to be able to connect to the internet and the selected services. This happens outside of your app though and so your app does not need to declare the networking capability directly.

For reference, the rules of capability requirements are defined in
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Marketplace\Rules.xml"